# Django: How to set a quantity for every element in a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi guys I'm trying to make a an inventory app for tools in my workshop. I want to be able to know what tools are assigned to what toolbox and who is that tool box assigned to. I have a table called **Items** this table gets inherited by other tables that makeup a tool i.e.(To create cutting tool I have a table that is called **Cortadores** that inherits fields from **Item**. **Cortadores** has fields that are unique to cutting tools and **Items** has fields that are common for all tools) I also have the tables: **Carritos** and **Empleados**. What im attempting to do is build a table **Carritos** tha has all tools assigned to it and **Empleados** that the cart is assigned to.

my **models.py**

```
class Carritos(models.Model):
    no_carrito = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    herramienta = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    f_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    f_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Carritos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.no_carrito
```

I was not intending to create a view for it, I wanted to be able to create and make changes to **carritos** from the Admin page. I get a list of tools available and are able to  select multiple tools. what I don't know is how to define a quantity per tool the **carrito** has. i.e.( If I wanted to assing 2 cutters to a carrito, how could I go about it )

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? Thanks